# Artifactory - Intermittently Slow response times

Tags: artifactory

We are having issues with gradle builds when integrated with our local Artifactory 5.8.4 server.  Gradle gives exceptions like this: `Read timed out`.

To troubleshoot this, we used the following (redacted) curl command, and occasionally it will take up to 30-60 seconds to respond:

```
time curl -u username:password http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot/com/redacted/product/maven-metadata.xml
```

below is the output from the `request.log` on the artifactory server:

```
20180219144146|30190|REQUEST|172.x.x.51|username|GET|/libs-snapshot/com/redacted/product/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|200|411
```

the value `30190` shows that the request is taking 30sec to process for some reason

any ideas of what we can try to resolve this?

--- update ---

as requested by @DrorBereznitsky, i have attached a trace to this endpoint (using curl) below.  Note that the delay seems to be before the trace even starts - this can be seen by the output of the `time` command showing a clock duration of: `real 0m30.316s`

```
[root@afactory ]# time curl -u username:password http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot/com/redacted/product/maven-metadata.xml?trace
Request ID: c1fdcf4f
Repo Path ID: libs-snapshot:com/redacted/product/maven-metadata.xml
Method Name: GET
User: username
Time: 2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00
Thread: http-nio-8081-exec-35
Steps: 
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Received request
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Request source = 127.0.0.1, Last modified = 01-01-70 00:59:59 +01:00, If modified since = -1, Thread name = http-nio-8081-exec-35
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Executing any BeforeDownloadRequest user plugins that may exist
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Retrieving info from {} repository '{}' type 
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Consulting the virtual repo download strategy
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Trying to retrieve resource info from the local storage
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Unable to find resource in libs-snapshot:com/redacted/product/maven-metadata.xml
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Intercepting cached virtual resource with 'PomInterceptor'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Intercepting cached virtual resource with 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Searching for info in aggregated repositories
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Preparing list of aggregated repositories to search in
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Appending the nested virtual repository 'libs-snapshot'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Appending the nested virtual repository 'remote-repos'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Appending the nested virtual repository 'remote-repos'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Appending collective local repositories
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Appending collective local cache repositories
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Appending collective remote repositories
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Intercepting info request with 'PomInterceptor'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.281+01:00 Intercepting info request with 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.282+01:00 The requested resource isn't pre-resolved
2018-02-23T10:14:36.282+01:00 Target repository isn't virtual - verifying that downloading is allowed
2018-02-23T10:14:36.282+01:00 Creating a resource handle from 'libs-snapshot-local:com/redacted/product/maven-metadata.xml'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.282+01:00 Identified requested resource as a file
2018-02-23T10:14:36.282+01:00 Requested resource is an ordinary artifact - using normal content handle with length '411'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.284+01:00 Unable to find resource in ext-snapshot-local:com/redacted/product/maven-metadata.xml
2018-02-23T10:14:36.287+01:00 Info request was intercepted by 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.287+01:00 Received resource from an interceptor - returning
2018-02-23T10:14:36.287+01:00 Returning resource as found in the aggregated repositories
2018-02-23T10:14:36.287+01:00 Intercepting found resource with 'PomInterceptor'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.287+01:00 Intercepting found resource with 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.287+01:00 Requested resource is found = true
2018-02-23T10:14:36.287+01:00 Request is HEAD = false
2018-02-23T10:14:36.287+01:00 Request is for a checksum = false
2018-02-23T10:14:36.288+01:00 Target repository is not remote or doesn't store locally = true
2018-02-23T10:14:36.288+01:00 Requested resource was not modified = false
2018-02-23T10:14:36.288+01:00 Responding with found resource
2018-02-23T10:14:36.288+01:00 Executing any AltResponse user plugins that may exist
2018-02-23T10:14:36.288+01:00 Alternative response status is set to -1 and message to 'null'
2018-02-23T10:14:36.288+01:00 Found no alternative content handles
2018-02-23T10:14:36.288+01:00 Retrieving a content handle from target repo
2018-02-23T10:14:36.288+01:00 The requested resource is already resolved - using a string resource handle
2018-02-23T10:14:36.288+01:00 Executing any BeforeDownload user plugins that may exist
2018-02-23T10:14:36.288+01:00 Responding with selected content handle
2018-02-23T10:14:36.300+01:00 Request succeeded

real    0m30.316s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.011s
```

Comment: 30-60 is slow for such a request. Can you attach the output of a trace request for the maven-metadata.xml - http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot/com/redacted/product/maven-metadata.xml?trace

Comment: hi @DrorBereznitsky , thanks for your reply. i have added the trace to the original question

Comment: is your Artifactory connected to an LDAP server?

Comment: Thanks @DrorBereznitsky. Yes we do have an LDAP (samba4 AD) backend for authentication. However the account that is having issues above, is a local, non-LDAP account

Comment: Even if you are authenticating with a local user, Artifactory will still go to LDAP (for multiple reasons that be hard to specify in a comment). I suggest testing the connectivity with your LDAP server. A slow LDAP connection is a common cause for such a slow response.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @DrorBereznitsky - disabling all LDAP integration seems to have resolved this issue.

Comment: So to further troubleshoot this, i have changed the following Artifactory LDAP settings:

[1] Changed the LDAP URL so it includes the full DN to the OU that contains our users: `ldaps://redacted-server-hostname:636/ou=company-staff,ou=company-users,dc=subdomain,dc=company,dc=com`




    [2] Disabled `Search Sub-tree` option

so far this seems to have improved things. but i will provide further feedback on this after monitoring for a few days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I was able to workaround/resolve this, by changing the following Artifactory LDAP settings:

[1] Changed the LDAP URL so it includes the full DN to the OU that contains our users:

```
ldaps://redacted-server-hostname:636/ou=company-staff,ou=company-users,dc=subdomain,dc=company,dc=com
```

[2] Disabled Search Sub-tree option.

this seems to have improved performance markedly

Answer (score 0):

*maven-metadata.xml* is a book-keeping XML file that sits at the root of an artifact and lists all the versions for a given artifact.

For example, with this hierarchy

```
com
  \---redacted
      \---product
            \---maven-metadata.xml
            \---2.7.5
            \---2.7.7
```

The file will contain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.redacted</groupId>
  <artifactId>product</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>2.7.7</latest>
    <release>2.7.7</release>
    <versions>
      <version>2.7.5</version>
      <version>2.7.7</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20180219142822</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

When you upload a new version 2.7.8 for this artifact, the server will:

- lock *maven-metadata.xml*
- insert the new version 2.7.8
- update *maven-metadata.xml*
- unlock *maven-metadata.xml*

So I am pretty sure that the times when this file takes time to retrieve is when a SNAPSHOT version of the same artifact is uploaded.

This is by design of course, Artifactory goes to great lengths to prevent you from receiving a stale file.
I don't think you should look into fixing this...

Comment: the issue was related to LDAP integration. See comments to original question for more info

Comment: OK, that makes sense somehow, the locking duration on the _maven-metadata.xml_ is much longer than normal because the duration of every upload is weighed down by checks in LDAP.
I would not have suspected LDAP integration from the symptoms, that is a nice find.

Answer (score -1):

Tomcat heavily relies on SecureRandom class to provide random values. It can cause delays during startup if entropy source that is used to initialize SecureRandom is short of entropy.

There is a way to configure JRE to use a non-blocking entropy source by setting the following system property:

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

Adding this option to current `JAVA_OPTS` may resolve your timeout problem.

Comment: thanks for the comment @rosencreuz.  I added this to the JAVA_OPTIONS in the `/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default` file - but unfortunately this has not resolved this behaviour

Comment: i have also just installed `haveged` to increase entropy on that VM, to see if that helps.  I will advise if this improves things

Comment: unfortanately neither adding this option, nor installing haveged improved the situation.  The issue was in fact related to LDAP integration